# CSS/XPATH selector management using python's dictionary

Tags: webdriver, unit-tests, python

I have a lot of functional tests in Python.
As expected , they use a wide variety of css/xpath selectors .

I think I read somewhere that a practice is to have a dictionary where each selector would be stored.
So, when a random selector in a random page changes for some reason, then theoretically it's selectors and/or attributes (id,name) would be changed only one time in this dictionary.

Is this possible?

And if yes, what would be the structure of the dictionary/list/array?
I am currently familiarizing myself with the theory of lists and dictionaries to see how to implement it.

I think that one solution would be:

```
[button1, css_selector, xpath_selector, page_found, description]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a general Python programming question rather than a test question.

As a general programming practice, it is a good idea to give a constant a name, especially if the constant is used more than once.

How you manage those names depends on your goal.  You might do this:

```
XPATH = "xpath"
CSS = "css"
SELECTOR_TYPE = "selectorType"
SELECTOR = "selector"
// etc.

BUTTON1 = {SELECTOR_TYPE: XPATH, SELECTOR: "//input[@id='loginSubmitButton']"}
BUTTON2 = {SELECTOR_TYPE: XPATH, SELECTOR: "//input[@id='loginCancelButton']"}
USERNAME_FIELD = {SELECTOR_TYPE: CSS, SELECTOR: "form input[name='username']"}
```

I omitted `page_found` and `description` because you didn't explain what those are.

You might even want to put all those definitions in a dictionary so that you can pass them around as a group, like this:

```
login_selectors = { 'button1': {SELECTOR_TYPE: XPATH, SELECTOR: "//input[@id='loginSubmitButton']"},
                    'button2': {SELECTOR_TYPE: XPATH, SELECTOR: "//input[@id='loginCancelButton']"}
                    'username_field': {SELECTOR_TYPE: CSS, SELECTOR: "form input[name='username']"}}
```